# Reuse of ResultSet member variable in a multi-threaded environment

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, resultset

I am implementing a code that uses JDBC driver.

Below is the code that I made.

```
public class MysqlUtils {
    public Connection conn;
    public ResultSet rs;
    public PreparedStatement stmt;

    public MysqlUtils(String address, String id, String passwd) {
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(address, id, passwd);
            stmt = null;
            rs = null;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // error management
        }
    }

    public void getSomeData(long id) {
        try {
            stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM some_table");
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            rs.next();
            System.out.println(rs.getString("some_column");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // error management
        }
    }
}
```

I have declared Connection conn, ResultSet rs, PreparedStatement stmt as member variables because somehow I thought that might help me enhance performance.

I have a couple of questions.

1. If I call getSomeData() consecutively, will stmt and rs be assigned new objects every time?
2. Regardless of the answer to the question above, if I run this code in a multi-threaded environment(multiple threads using MysqlUtils class), will there be a mix-up because I didn't declare ResultSet rs in getSomeData()?
3. Was declaring Connection conn, ResultSet rs, PreparedStatement stmt as member variables a bad choice? In other words, is my implementation of JDBC a viable one?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You should have to populate `List<T>`.

Comment: ...or pass data to a thread pool to process with only one thread reading the ResultSet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes. The method will be executed, and thus `stmt` and `rs` will take new values. Of course, you might have multiple instances of your class, and thus multiple instances of those two fields.
2. Yes. This code is completele thread-**un**safe. Public fields in general should almost always be avoided. Especially in a multi-threaded environment
3. Yes, it's a bad choice. The scope of a variable should be as small as possible. And these variables are used in a single method, and reassigned every time. They should be local variable.

Also:

- a method `getSomeData()` should return something, and not just printing something
- the ResultSet and the Statement should be closed, in a finally block
- I hope the error management doesn't consist in swallowing the exception

I would advise using spring-jdbc, which takes care of all the plumbing code for you, and avoids all the problems your code currently has.

Comment: I am looking at Spring JDBC Template right now. This is a whole new world for me. Thanks for the tip!!

Answer (score 0):

Do not use ResultSet outside of the method.... with while(rs.next) (rs=resultSet) you are looping through a database table and retrieving values!